# Excel COUNTIFS function

Tags: excel

In excel I am having trouble with the COUNTIFS function.  I have a large spreadsheet with several thousand line items – each row contains information on a specific corporate bond.  Many bonds have been issued by the same company – the company name is in column F.  I have also categorized each company by industry (column AE).  My goal is to find the number of companies (not bonds) within each industry.

I used the following formula to see that I have 20 bonds issued by companies within the advertising industry:

```
=COUNTIFS($AE$15:$AE$5000,"Advertising")
```

But many of these were issued by the same company.  There are actually only 8 different companies in column AE – I sorted all bonds by industry and then for the advertising companies, the following formula returned “8”:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(F15:F34,F15:F34,0),MATCH(F15:F34,F15:F34,0))>0,1)).
```

How can I have one formula to see the number of discrete companies in each industry, without having to sort by industry and then take a count?  I tried to combine the above 2 functions into one but this didn’t work (it returned “0”).  My attempt is below:

```
=COUNTIFS($AE$15:$AE$4987,"Advertising",$F$15:$F$4987,SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(F15:F4987,F15:F4987,0),MATCH(F15:F4987,F15:F4987,0))>0,1)))
```

Can anyone help me with this? Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
{=SUM(IF(MATCH(F15:F34, F15:F34, 0)>=(ROW(F15:F34)-MIN(ROW(F15:F34))+1), 1, 0))}
```

It's an array formula, so don't enter the curly brackets and press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` instead of just `Enter`.

Kudos to [www.get-digital-help.com](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/09/count-unique-values-in-a-column-in-excel/) for the help (I'm not affiliated!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(($AE$15:$AE$4987="Advertising")/COUNTIFS($F$15:$F$4987,$F$15:$F$4987,$AE$15:$AE$4987,"Advertising"),0))
```

It's an array formula, so you have to press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` when you paste it in the formula bar.